# SDK android emulator for flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am installing andoid sdk in Intelli idea the error occuring in installation is  :

"java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 45350576. Expected 326723360 bytes.
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection closed at byte 45350576. Expected 326723360 bytes.."

I have downloaded and installed Intelli Idea have also installed flutter and dart PLUGINS now for i need emulator for it which i think is inside android sdk but its giving this error while installing it, I am basically learning dart flutter app development . please guide here how to use emulator using android sdk or anyway other than android sdk,

Comment: how about running android studio as administrator.

Comment: Make sure you have stable internet connection. If you use proxy, check that it is configured and do not block access to Android SDK resources. E.g. check the https://developer.android.com